# What is Maximum output length that Microsot.Text.Json can handle?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm about to make a massive API output and I concern about What's Microsot.Text.Json can handle.
My Project used a .net core 3.1.
My output is might 1000-3000 records;

Comment: Considering it supports streaming, there are very likely no size restrictions.

Comment: How about you build a small test and see if 3000 records works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/):

The developer written an ASP.NET Core app that generates data on the fly that is then serialized and deserialized from MVC controllers. We then varied the payload sizes and measured the results:

[image]

[image]

*For the most common payload sizes, System.Text.Json offers about 20% throughput increase in MVC during input and output formatting with a smaller memory footprint.*

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you very much.